# If $A>B>0$, can we always find a positive real number $\alpha$, $0<\alpha < 1$ such that $\alpha A \geq B $?

Tags: inequalities, matrix-analysis

Suppose we have positive-definite matrices $A$, $B$,   if $A>B>0$, can we always find a positive real number $\alpha$,  $0<\alpha < 1$ such that $ \alpha A \geq B $? If it has, then what is it?

Comment: $A>B$ means $A-B$ is positive-definite matrix.

Comment: Naturally. Thank you. Can't you prove a little sharper result: $\ \alpha\cdot A\ >\ B\ $ ?

Comment: If you mean my proposition is always true?

Comment: The real part the relevant expression related to $\ A - B\ $ is greater than certain $\ \epsilon > 0\ $ when evaluated on the unit sphere. If you change $\ A-B\ $ a little, i.e. if you change $\ A\ $ a little then it'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, after following your suggestion, I arrange it as follows: $A-B>\epsilon I$ which is equivalent to $A-\epsilon I> B$, also  $(I-\epsilon A^{-1}) A> B$, but this still can't show $\alpha A>B$ where $0< \alpha <1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the following.

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices and $S\subset\Bbb R^n$ be the unit sphere. Then positive definiteness of the matrix $A$ is equivalent to

$$m(A)=\min\{(Ax,x):x\in S\}>0.$$

Similarly, we  have

$$m(A-B)=\min\{(A-B)x,x):x\in S\}>0.$$

Put

$$M(B)=\max\{(Bx,x):x\in S\}>0.$$

Let $\alpha>\frac{M(B)}{m(A-B)+M(B)}<1$ be any number and $x\in S$ be any vector. Then

$$(\alpha Ax,x)-(Bx,x)=$$ $$\alpha((A-B)x,x)-(1-\alpha)(Bx,x)\ge$$ $$\alpha m(A-B)-(1-\alpha)M(B)=$$ $$\alpha(m(A-B)+M(B))-M(B)>$$ $$\frac{M(B)}{m(A-B)+M(B)} (m(A-B)+M(B))-M(B)>0.$$

Then

$$m(\alpha A-B)= \min\{(\alpha A-B)x,x):x\in S\}>0.$$

So the matrix $\alpha A−B$ is positive-definite, that is $\alpha A>B$

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I have 2 questions regarding your answer: 1) why let $A$ and $B$ be $n×n$ matrices and $S\subset R^n$ be the unit sphere? 2) $(\alpha Ax, x)-(Bx,x)>0$ may not imply   $m(\alpha A-B)>0$.

Comment: The general definition considers the complex field, not real.

Comment: Can $\alpha =\frac{M(B)}{M(B)+m(A-B)}$ such that $\alpha A\geq B$?

Comment: 1) I just fixed $n$. $S$ represents all non-zero vectors of the space $\Bbb R^n$. I considered only a real case, but I hope that the proof for the complex case is similar.

Comment: 2) The sphere $S$ is compact, so a continuous positive-valued function on $S$ attains its (positive) infimum  (that is why I wrote $”\min”$ instead of $”\inf”$.)

Comment: I expect that we can similarly prove that $\alpha A\ge B$ provided $\alpha=\frac{M(B)}{m(A-B)+M(B)}$.

Answer (score 3):

The @Alex Ravsky's answer is good, however, I still want to share my answer:

Proof: To prove $\alpha A\geq B$ where $0<\alpha<1$, we introduce an extra parameter $\lambda$, $0<\lambda<1$, $\alpha=1-\lambda$, such that $(1-\lambda)A\geq B$, which is equivalent to find a $\lambda$, $0<\lambda<1$, such that  $(1-\lambda)A\geq B$.

Arrange it, we get, $\lambda A\leq A-B$, to make it hold, we shall find $\lambda$ such that $\lambda A \leq \lambda_{\min}(A-B)I$ holds, which is equivalent to  $\lambda I \leq \lambda_{\min}(A-B) A^{-1}$. Further, let $\lambda = \frac{\lambda_{\min}(A-B)}{\lambda_{\max}(A)}$, the above equations are automatically satisfied.

Comment: I expect that, in fact, these $\lambda_{m\dots}$’s are the respective (minimal of maximal) eigenvalues of the matrices.

Comment: I couldn't understand well, 1) $\lambda_m$ refers which matrix? 2) Does ''minimal of maximal'' mean ''minimal to maximal'' ?   3) Is your answer implying my answer, that is, $\alpha = \frac{\lambda_{\max}(B)}{\lambda_{\max}(B)+\lambda_{\min}(A-B)}$ can infer to $\alpha=1-\lambda=\frac{\lambda_{\max}(A)-\lambda_{\min}(A-B)}{\lambda_{\max}(A)}$?

Comment: 1) I expect the following. Let $C$ be a positive definite symmetric $n\times n$ real-value matrix.  Then $$\min\{(Cx,x):x\in S\}=\lambda_{min}(C)$$ and $$\max\{(Cx,x):x\in S\}=\lambda_{max}(C),$$ where $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ are, respectively, minimal and maximal eigenvalues of the matrix $C$.

Comment: 2) It was a misprint, it should be “minimal or maximal instead. I am sorry.

Comment: 3) Oops, I'll think about it. Maybe one of these bounds  is not geater than the other.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it's clear now. Regarding your reply 1): I don't know $\lambda_{\min}$ or $\lambda_{\max}$ can be interpreted in this form. 3): I tried and arrived at $\frac{\lambda_{\max}(B)}{\lambda_{\max}(B)+\lambda_{\min}(A-B)} - \frac{\lambda_{\max}(A)-\lambda_{\min}(A-B)}{\lambda_{\max}(A)}=\frac{\lambda_{\min}(A-B)(\lambda_{\min}(A-B)-\lambda_{\max}(A)+\lambda_{\max}(B))}{\lambda_{\max}(A)\lambda_{\max}(B)+\lambda_{\max}(A)\lambda_{\min}(A-B)}$. Since it's hard to decide whether  $(\lambda_{\min}(A-B)-\lambda_{\max}(A)+\lambda_{\max}(B))>0$ or not, I stop here.

Comment: 1) It should follow from the fact (see, for instance, “Introduction to matrix analysis” by Richard Bellman (Ch.4.§7 in my Russian version)) that a symmetric real-valued matrix $C$ can be diagonalized by an orthogonal transformation of the basis (in particular, this transformation should preserve the unit sphere $S$). That is the respective quadratic form $(Cx, x)$ should transform to a weighted sum of squares $$\lambda_1 y_1^2+\dots+\lambda_n y_n^2,$$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $C$.So the matrix $C$ is positively definite iff all its eigenvalues are positive (Ch.4.§8).

Comment: 3) It seems the following. Yes, I arrived to this inequality too. From here we can proceed as follows. Let $x\in S$ be an arbitrary vector. Then 

$$(Ax, x)-(Bx, x)=((A-B)x , x)\ge\lambda_{min}(A-B)$$ and 

$$(Ax , x)\le\lambda_{max}(A).$$

So $$(Bx, x)\le \lambda_{max}(A)- \lambda_{min}(A-B).$$

Since the vector $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, we may claim that 

$$\lambda_{max} (B)\le \lambda_{max}(A)- \lambda_{min}(A-B).$$

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, everything is clear now. It seems that your bound is smaller than mine.